# How to Escape '//' special character while sourcing a file in scala

Tags: scala

I have a file path which has // in it.I am unable to source the file in SCALA while trying to read the file(source.fromFile("path")).It's saying unable to find the path at the location,since it taking only one / instead of //.
How to read the file with such path?

I tried keeping the path in """ but didn't work

```scala
val source_full_storage_account_name=adls
val table_name=test_table
val dir="dfss://table1@" + source_full_storage_account_name +"/test/Tables"
println("path is : " +dir)
val upd_qry=Source.fromFile(dir+"/"+table_name+".sql").getLines.mkString
```

Iam getting correct path in print where as the error says the path not found

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: val source_full_storage_account_name=adls
val table_name=test_table
val dir="dfss://table1@" + source_full_storage_account_name +"/test/Tables"
println("path is : " +dir)
val upd_qry=Source.fromFile(dir+"/"+table_name+".sql").getLines.mkString

Comment: Here I am trying to read sql file which is in ADLS

Comment: Update your original question rather than adding a comment.

Comment: What makes you think the `//` is escaped?

Comment: did you get an error message executing that code?  have you checked what is the path you are passing as parameter doing `println(dir+"/"+table_name+".sql")`? have you tried to access manually from a console to that file manually using the path in the previous step? Please provide more context. Instead of adding comments, click on `edit` button to add more information. I suggest to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [how to provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think `Source.fromFile(String)` is probably limited to local files and is trying to interpret those two slashes a single one (as it happens if you `cd //`). You might want to try with `Source.fromFile(URI)`. You can probably just pass the string as is and let the `java.net.URI` class parse it, as in `Source.fromFile(new URI(s"$dir/$table_name.sql"))`.

Comment: @stefanobaghino Tried the above thing it didn't work. 'URI scheme is not "file"' got the above error

Comment: Looks like `Source.fromFile` is only able to load local files. You probably want to consult the documentation of ADLS with regards to accessing it from the JVM. I wouldn't assume that the Scala standard library comes with native support for it. Maybe this page could help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what kind of environment you are operating in, but judging by the fact that the path components in your path seem to be separated by forward slashes (`/`), I am going to assume a POSIX-*ish* / Unix-*ish* environment. (The "other" popular environment would be a DOS-*ish* / Windows-*ish* environment, which uses backslashes (`\`) as path component separators, although confusingly, Windows also accepts forward slashes.)

If my assumption of a POSIX-*ish* environment is correct, then Scala is behaving correctly: according to [Section 3.271 *Pathname*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271) of the [*Base Definitions (XBD)* Volume](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xbd.html) of [POSIX.1-2017, 2018 Edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> ***Multiple successive <slash>*** characters are considered to be the ***same as one <slash>***, except for the case of exactly two leading <slash> characters.

So, according to the POSIX specification, Scala is behaving correctly, as `dfss://table1@foobar/test/Tables` and `dfss:/table1@foobar/test/Tables` are the *exact same path* (as are `dfss://///////table1@foobar/test/Tables` or `dfss:/table1@foobar//test/Tables` or `dfss:/table1@foobar/test//Tables` or any other arbitrary combination).

Multiple slashes are *only* special *IFF* there are *exactly two* slashes *and* they are at the *beginning of the path*.

In other words, `//foo//bar` is special and it would be illegal to transform it to `//foo/bar`, `/foo//bar`, or `/foo/bar`, but `///foo/bar`, `foo//bar`, or `/foo//bar` are not special.

See [Section 4.13 *Pathname Resolution*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13) [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> If a pathname ***begins with two successive <slash> characters***, the ***first component*** following the leading <slash> characters may be interpreted in an ***implementation-defined manner***, although ***more than two leading <slash> characters*** shall be ***treated as a single <slash> character***.

According to the POSIX specification, the path `dfss://table1@foobar/test/Tables` is interpreted as follows:

1. Look up the directory entry named `dfss:` in the [current working directory](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of the current process.
2. Look up the directory entry named `table1@foobar` in the directory returned by step #1.
3. Look up the directory entry named `test` in the directory returned by step #2.
4. Look up the directory entry named `Tables` in the directory returned by step #3.

The directory entry returned by step #4 is the file you are looking for.

Obviously, as per the error message you posted, that file does not exist on your computer in the current working directory.

*However*, the colon (`:`) followed by the double forward slash (`//`) gives us an important hint: it looks like what you have there is, in fact, *not a path at all*, it is a [*Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier). That would also mean that you are not looking for a *file* at all, but for a *resource*.

In that case, the URI should be interpreted like this, according to [RFC 3986 *Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986):

1. A URI *Scheme* of `dfss`,
2. An *Authority* of `table1@foobar`

   1. Consisting of a *Userinfo* of `table1` and
   2. A *Host* of `foobar`
   3. With the *Port* being empty,
3. A *Path* of `/test/Tables`,
4. An empty *Query*, and
5. An empty *Fragment*.

The *URI Scheme*, i.e. in this case `dfss` tells you how to interpret the rest of the URI. Unfortunately, `dfss` does not seem to be officially registered in the [official IANA registry of *Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) Schemes*](https://iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml), so it is not possible to tell how the URI should be interpreted. Not even [Google has heard of it](https://google.com/search?q=%22dfss%22+uri+scheme).

So, in summary, what you have there is not a path, it is a URI, identifying not a file but a resource. That's why a library for opening files from a path doesn't work. You need a library for opening resources from a URI, but not *any* library, you need one that understands the `dfss` URI Scheme.